# Get rows where date fits a specific pattern. MySQL

Tags: php, mysql, date

I'm creating an online booking system that can have recurring dates e.g.

- every week
- every 2 weeks
- first {day} of month
- second {day} of month
- third {day} of month
  ...etc.

My main issue is that one user could create a one-off booking that's 5 years in the future (not likely, but possible) and I want to be able to display clashes that will occur.
I know I could just get the MAX(date) and then use PHP to create an array of possible date between now and the furthest booking away and just use

```
WHERE `date` IN ({big array of dates})
```

but I was wondering if there is a way that I can get MySQL to calculate the dates for me.
My MySQL knowledge isn't beginner but it's still quite basic.

Thanks.

**EDIT**

Both one-off and recurring events are stored as only one row. Each row has a `recurring_type` (1-8) and `recurring_day` (1-7) these can both be NULL which indicates that they're one-offs.

Below is the array of recurring types

```
array(
    1 => 'every_week',
    2 => 'every_2_weeks',
    3 => 'every_3_weeks',
    4 => 'every_4_weeks',
    5 => 'first_day_of_month',
    6 => 'second_day_of_month',
    7 => 'third_day_of_month',
    8 => 'forth_day_of_month',
);
```

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly, there is a faster way (which, I am assuming, is what you are looking for):
If you define your date as a primary key, and do a "INSERT IGNORE", you can then query the affectedRows. If that is 0, you have a clash.

I hope it helps :)

Comment: I see what you've done there. I should have pointed out that way I handle recurring events. (I'll put this in my question as well) basically both one-off and recurring events only take up one row in the table and the recurring events have a field for recurring type and recurring day which get handled with PHP.

Comment: Ok, I see what you mean. Can't you use my solution and additionally query the recurring date? like "INSERT IGNORE ... SET `date` = "2014-05-23" , recurringDate = '<date>'" ?

Comment: Not really because there is only one date field this only represents the first date of the reoccurrence. After that I'm just using PHP to calculate if an entry fits with a certain date.

Comment: Ok, your updated question makes it clear - and my approach worthless, sorry :)